# How to divide big decimal in java

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

I have an issue with Big decimal variable.
I want to divide it, and the problem is that the deviation results is not correct.
the variable called bvalue = 405000000
and I want to divide it by 1000000. the problem that I am facing is that the response is 1. and not 405 as expected.
I used

```
bvalue = bvalue.divide(bvalue,1000000,RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

how can I divide big decimal correctly? by 1000000
regards

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the wrong `.divide()` function you wanted the following

```
BigDecimal bvalue = new BigDecimal(405000000);
BigDecimal avalue = new BigDecimal(1000000);
System.out.println(bvalue.divide(avalue, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks almost like a typo to me, because you are dividing a number by itself:

```
bvalue = bvalue.divide(bvalue, 1000000, RoundingMode.CEILING);
         ^^^           ^^^  numerator = denominator
```

Hence the quotient of 1 is to be expected.

I think this is what you have in mind:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("405000000");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1000000");
BigDecimal result = a.divide(b, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
System.out.println(result);
```

### Demo